# Login Loop on Ubuntu 20.04 with no . XAuthority

Tags: upgrade, login, login-screen

I have gotten into a login loop after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.
The cause might be that I upgraded from root?

**Do you know any solutions to this?**
(I have tried most of them but they didn't work)

Comment: Any closed sourced module like nvidia on your System; if so `dkms status` und `uname -a` please add both to your question. Have you tried to start the last bionic kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open tty3 screen

type `startx`

run: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

logout, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> until you see the login.

Comment: Startx isnt working mate I gotta resolve startx first

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg

Comment: you may also need to change your password. but I'm not sure.

Comment: No problem in changing password- but I can't connect to WiFi mate do you know how to connect?(thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this)

Comment: this answer always help me for wifi problems: https://askubuntu.com/a/684443/1297757

Comment: Okay I solved WiFi problems but startx is closing immediately. Is it wrong to do  sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 from tty?

Comment: I SOLVED IT through fixing the broken upgrade (the commands you gave me in the previous post) !!! Thanks a lot for your time mate !!

Comment: Glad to see it works now, friend. :)